# URL Rewriting (IIS) - how to represent an url pattern in match tag

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-6

I have a url rewrite rule for my IIS 7 server which is following:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="topcontent">
           <match url=".*">
                <action type="rewrite" url="mysite.com/{R:0}"/>
           </match>
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Now I have to provide an exception to this rule, for a particular location, which is 'http://tempurl94.goto.com/?q=x&m=y' where 'http://tempurl94.goto.com' will always be there
in the url, and query parameter q and m may vary. So we have to write different rule for
this url. How to write a different (match url=?).

May be I can write a rule before the 'topcontent' rule and say stopProcessing='true'.
But I need to know what should I write inside `<match url=' ? '>` and what should I write in `<action>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `conditions` element to the new rule. Put the new rule before the current one and set `stopProcessing` to `true` as you mentioned.

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^tempurl94\.goto\.com$" />
</conditions>
```